# How to independent run the intellij plugin in multiple project?(intellij plugin develop)

Tags: intellij-idea, mybatis, jetbrains-ide, intellij-plugin

i have rewrite the intellij plugin: **MyBatis Log Plugin**.
**The plugin feature is restore the mybatis generate sql to original whole executable sql.**
And i have open the source on github:
[MyBatis Log Plugin](https://github.com/kookob/mybatis-log-plugin)
I want run this plugin on every different project independent.
But now i have a problem can't to solve.
When i enable the plugin, it only take effect on the last start. and output the whole sql on the last console.
How can i fix this bug?
Anyone who can help me to review the code and points out the problem.
Thank you!
And when i fix this bug, i will redistribution it on jetbrains plugin repository.

Answer (score 0):

I hava solve my problem.
Every project i had new ConsoleView Object.
And output the log bind the project consoleView.